# How to copy instance of RequestSpecification from base class

Tags: java, rest-assured

In my base I have created request specification by providing base URI, header, etc,

```
RequestSpecification base = given().baseUri( " http://xyz/" )
                                   .port( 8080 )
                                   .header( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
```

And in my sub `classB` I copied the base instance and added path param to in sub class

```
RequestSpecification classB= base.given()
classB.pathParam("name", "abc" );
```

but when I tried to copy the base to another sub class (which do not need path param) it is throwing exception as Invalid number of path parameters. Expected 1, was 0 ,

while updating path param in `ClassB`, base class also get mutate, since base and sub class are pointing to the same object.
Is there any way to copy base class object without getting updated .
Your Input Would Be Greatly Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of;

```
RequestSpecification classB = base.given();
classB.pathParam("name", "abc" );
```

try;

```
RequestSpecification classB = given().spec(base);
```

Here `spec(RequestSpecification requestSpecification)` add the data from pre-defined RequestSpecification object.

Check the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/latest/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html#spec-io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification-)

Comment: Perfect!! ,  Thanks @kaweesha